# Webpack becomes slower each build

Tags: webpack

So I have a very small codebase. I only have 4 webpages and an authentication system in AngularJs.

I am using webpack to transpile from ES6 and TypeScript.

The first build is 2232ms.

My compilation consists of 2 rounds, where the first round is always around 100ms, but the second round becomes longer and longer to about 15s in a matter of minutes, while barely adding any new code.

Here I comment out the exact same variable each time, doesn't matter what code I change fyi.

Time: 1240ms
Time: 1077ms
Time: 1388ms
Time: 1823ms
Time: 2625ms
Time: 3038ms
Time: 3967ms
Time: 4371ms
Time: 4759ms
Time: 5172ms
Time: 5745ms
Time: 6148ms
Time: 6579ms
Time: 7144ms

And this goes on and on and on..

My **webpack config** file (from the ui-router sample project):

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var DEV_SERVER = process.argv[1].indexOf('webpack-dev-server') !== -1;
var DEV = DEV_SERVER || process.env.DEV;

var plugins = [
  new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin({
    multiStep: true
  })
];
if (!DEV) {
  plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ sourceMap: true, }));
}
plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({ name: 'vendor' }));


module.exports = {
  entry: {
    "sampleapp": "./app/bootstrap/bootstrap.js",

    "vendor": [
      'angular',
      'oclazyload',
      '@uirouter/core',
      '@uirouter/angularjs',
      '@uirouter/visualizer',
      '@uirouter/sticky-states',
      '@uirouter/dsr',
    ],
  },

  devtool: DEV ? 'eval-source-map' :'eval-source-map', // change for production to source-map

  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "_bundles"),
    publicPath: '_bundles/',
    filename: "[name].js",
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js']
  },

  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    //hot: true,
    inline: true,

    host: 'localhost', // Defaults to `localhost`
    port: 8080, // Defaults to 8080
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:3000/',
        secure: false
      }
    }
  },

  plugins: plugins,

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: ["source-map-loader"],
        enforce: "pre",
        exclude: [/@uirouter/]
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: { loader: 'babel-loader', options: { presets: ['babel-preset-es2015'] } },
      }
    ]
  },
};
```

**webpack version: 2.6.1**

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by removing the webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin. It wasn't necessary after all anyway, because my app is still hot reloading without it.